# How to add link on menu items in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, category, menu, submenu

I have added Offer section in menu items. I treated Offer has one of the category and added 2 sub section i.e 1) 100 and 2) 50 percent offer.

Now I want to add link for sub section 100 and 50 percent

Comment: why -1? 
Suggestions area also welcome

Comment: You have category whose name is Offer and which has two sub category 100 % offer and 50 % offer right ? and you want to display a pages for sub category right?

Comment: yes... you are right

Comment: you want to display sub category in main category page ?

Comment: no ......................

Comment: then in category if you set include navigation -> yes then it will display in menu

Comment: yes, I have already set navigation to yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a static block for your sub category from **Cms->Static Blocks**

2) Open your sub category from **Catalog->Manage Category**.

3) Under **Display Setting** change **Display Mode** to **Static block only**.

4) From **CMS Block** select your created block.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I think this link will help - http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar.html#gref

Comment: yes this is also possible but i think providing directly a block could be better way rather than creating redirection any way its your choice.

Comment: yes, yours one is more easy